# Sql Alchemy filter / where clause joined by OR not AND

Tags: sqlalchemy, where-clause

I want to select a bunch distinct records based off a composite key. In `SQL` I'd write something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM security WHERE (
    exchange_code = 'exchange_code_1' AND code = 'code_1') 
    OR (exchange_code = 'exchange_code_2' AND code = 'code_2')
    ...
    OR (exchange_code = 'exchange_code_N' AND code = 'code_N')
)
```

With `SQLAlchemy` I'd like to use the filter clause like:

```
query = sess.query(Security)
[query.filter(
    and_(Security.exchange_code == security.exchange_code, 
    Security.code == security.code)
) for security in securities]
result = query.all()
```

The problem is `filter` and `where` join clauses with an AND not an OR... is there some way to use filter with OR?

Or is my only choice to generate a bunch of individual select's and `UNION` them? Something like:

```
first = exchanges.pop()
query = reduce(lambda query, exchange: query.union(exchange.pk_query),
                   first.pk_query())
query.all()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`or_`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.or_):

```
query = sess.query(Security).filter(
    or_(*(and_(Security.exchange_code == security.exchange_code, 
               Security.code == security.code)
          for security in securities)))
```

If your database supports it, you should use [`tuple_`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.tuple_) instead.

Comment: I tried `or_(and_(Security.exchange_code == security.exchange_code, 
               Security.code == security.code)` what does the `*()` do? Fairly new to python...

Comment: @Martinffx `(and_(...) for security in securities)` is a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/). It's a shorthand for writing a generator. The `*` operator unpacks (splats) the generator into arguments.

Comment: cool, will give that and the tuple a try.. I'm using the postgres :-)